# SqlConnection Connection String not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I understand there are many questions already covering this subject, but I am unable to find one that solves my problem.

I am pretty sure that my connection string is correct, because I am copying it directly from the database's "ConnectionString" property, and then just escaping slashes and quotation marks in the string.

My code looks like this:

```
con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Initial Catalog=\"C:\\USERS\\PC\\DOCUMENTS\\VISUAL STUDIO 2013\\PROJECTS\\WEBAPPLICATION9\\WEBAPPLICATION9\\APP_DATA\\DATABASE1.MDF\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
con.Open();
```

When I run my code, I am given an SqlException that simply says "Cannot connect to database."

Comment: May I suggest that use use `@` (string literals) instead of escaping everything?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the path to your app data folder, use the app data special variable, ex: `|DataDirectory|\\database1.mdf`.

Comment: @mason `DataDirectory` only works with `AttachDbFilename`, the OP is using `initial catalog` which I bet is the real source of the problem. (but your advice is good too). I have not ever used `AttachDbFilename` in production and don't know the pitfalls of using it so I don't want to post as an answer.

Comment: |DataDirectory| did it!  @mason if you add an answer I'll accept it.  I don't know what was wrong with my path! I had tried a lot of different things, but somehow missed this |DataDirectory| thing.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I will keep that in mind if transitioning this code to a production environment.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DataDirectory instead of a hardcoded path to your database file when your database file resides in your `~/App_Data/` folder.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Initial Catalog=\"|DataDirectory|\\database1.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
```

Answer (score 1):

For readability and sanity, you should do something like this.

```
con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False", @"(LocalDB)\\v11.0", @"C:\USERS\PC\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2013\PROJECTS\WEBAPPLICATION9\WEBAPPLICATION9\APP_DATA\DATABASE1.MDF");
con.Open();
```

Comment: While it doesn't solve my problem, I appreciate the tip!

Comment: [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) is a far better option that. In addition it handles all special characters automatically too.